# Find the leaf node per group in a hierarchical tree

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables. The type column in table T1, follows a hierarchy from table T2. I want to list the types per name in table T1 and find the leaf per name.

```
      T1                              T2
name      type                    type       parent
----------------                --------------------
a1      person                |  artist     person       
a1      artist                |  actor      artist
a2      person                |  athlete    person
a2      athlete               |  person       ''
a3      person                       
a3      artist                
a3      actor
```

The usual query to find the leaf nodes per name would not work here

```
select a.* from T1 a left join   T2 b on a.type = b.parent where b.parent is null; 
a2      athlete               
a3      actor
```

but I am looking for this output (the leaf node per group name)

```
a1      artist                
a2      athlete               
a3      actor
```

in other words I want to find leaf node per name so in case of a1, the leaf node between [person,artist] would be artist and for a3 [person, artist,actor], it will be actor.
is there a way to use GROUP BY and get the desired output

Comment: You need to explain clearer what you mean by farthest node.

Comment: Just re-wrote the question. Hope this is a bit clearer.

Comment: Is it mysql or sql-server? Your question is tagged with both.

Comment: it is a general sql question, I am using spark sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT
    t1.name AS anchor_name
    , t1.type AS type
    , t2.parent
    , 0 AS level
FROM #T1 t1 JOIN #T2 t2 ON t1.type = t2.type 

UNION ALL

SELECT cte.anchor_name, cte.type, t2.parent, cte.level+1
FROM cte JOIN #T2 t2 ON cte.parent = t2.type
)
, tmp AS (
    SELECT anchor_name, MAX(cte.level) AS max_level
    FROM cte 
    GROUP BY cte.anchor_name
)
SELECT cte.anchor_name as name, cte.type
FROM tmp JOIN cte ON cte.anchor_name = tmp.anchor_name AND cte.level = tmp.max_level
```

And this is the testing code:

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 (
    name VARCHAR(2)
    , type VARCHAR(MAX)
    );

CREATE TABLE #T2 (
    type VARCHAR(MAX)
    , parent VARCHAR(MAX)
    );

INSERT INTO #T1 (name, type)
VALUES
('a1', 'artist')
,('a1', 'person')
,('a2', 'person')
,('a2', 'athlete')
,('a3', 'person')
,('a3', 'artist')
,('a3', 'actor');

INSERT INTO #T2 (type, parent)
VALUES
('artist'    , 'person')
,('actor'     , 'artist')
,('athlete'   , 'person')
,('person'    ,   '');


SELECT *
FROM #T1;

SELECT *
FROM #T2;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        t1.name AS anchor_name
        , t1.type AS type
        , t2.parent
        , 0 AS level
    FROM #T1 t1 JOIN #T2 t2 ON t1.type = t2.type 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cte.anchor_name, cte.type, t2.parent, cte.level+1
    FROM cte JOIN #T2 t2 ON cte.parent = t2.type
    )
, tmp AS (
    SELECT anchor_name, MAX(cte.level) AS max_level
    FROM cte 
    GROUP BY cte.anchor_name
)
SELECT cte.anchor_name as name, cte.type
FROM tmp JOIN cte ON cte.anchor_name = tmp.anchor_name AND cte.level = tmp.max_level
```

http://rextester.com/TRD23741

Comment: edited the question for clarity. the above tables are snapshots of much bigger tables

Comment: @user1848018 Modified the answer